# Adding a Menu to the Visual Studio Menu Bar within an Add-In

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, add-in, menubar

Is it possible to create an add a custom menu to the main menu bar in Visual Studio within an Add-In?

I want the Add-In to create a company specific menu if it does not already exist and then add its own specific command to that menu. That way if multiple Add-Ins are supplied then they can all add the commands to the same menu.

I have found an [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165473.aspx) for a walkthrough in creating a VSPackage which does this but not from within an Add-In and it requires its own specific installation/registration.

Comment: Menu and submenus and separator lines too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static CommandBarControl GetCustomMenu(DTE2 applicationObject)
    {
        //Find the MenuBar command bar, which is the top-level command bar holding all the main menu items
        CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

        //Find the Tools command bar on the MenuBar command bar as we want to add it before it
        CommandBarControl toolsControl = menuBarCommandBar.Controls["Tools"];

        CommandBarControl myMenu;

        try
        {
            // Get the menu bar if it already exists
            myMenu = menuBarCommandBar.Controls["My Menu"];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Doesnt exist so crate a new one.
            myMenu = menuBarCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Id: 1234567890, Before: toolsControl.Index - 1);
            myMenu.Caption = "My Menu"];;
        }
        return myMenu;
    }
```