# Create parent menu in AddIn using c#

Tags: c#, add-in, menubar

I want to add menu to visual studio in AddIn.
I found how to create submenu item in [Expose an Add-In on the Tools Menu (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165625.aspx), but I want to create primary menu (like 'File', 'Edit', 'View' etc.)
How can I do that using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use this:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = 
    ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

CommandBarPopup myNewPopUpControl = 
    menuBarCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup) as CommandBarPopup;

myNewPopUpControl.Caption = "MyMenu";
myNewPopUpControl.Visible = true;
```

First line is from the OnConnection of the Add-In template.
As I experienced each element of Controls collection has a zero Id, so the arrangment might be problematic. Also you can create Buttons and PopUps with Automation (Exception will be thrown otherwise)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.commandbars.commandbarcontrols.add.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa190793(v=office.10).aspx

**Update**:
Your question seems to be a duplicate
[a question] [Adding a Menu to the Visual Studio Menu Bar within an Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987295/adding-a-menu-to-the-visual-studio-menu-bar-within-an-add-in) [a]

Comment: Maybe useful http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005003.aspx. I'm confused if you can create and menu, and **submenus and separator lines**.